# Слово "тюль" с числительными

Tags: числительные

Как правильно использовать слово ТЮЛЬ с числительными? Особенно непонятно с числительными после пяти.

Answer (score 2):

Тюль - это ткань. Поэтому говорим - один метр тюля, два метра (или рулона и т.п.)Когда мы говорим, что на окна висит тюль - имеем в виду штора из тюля. И тогда 5 штор. десять штор и т.д.

Answer (score 1):

Я не со всем согласен. Да, тюль - ткань, но иногда и неисчислимые существительные приобретают счетность. Сравните: cедьмая вода на киселе, (сплав) из пяти металлов, семь потов сошло и т.д. 
Поэтому формально нет причин отказывать существительному "тюль" в существовании счетных форм.
Из общих соображений: **два тюля, пять тюлей и т.д**.
Вот где такое можно употребить - это действительно загадка.
Разве что в формах наподобие "Это два разных тюля!", разумеется, чисто разговорных.